# Deduction fails on parameter, works on return value

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, sfinae

I tried to use `std::enable_if` on a function parameter to trigger SFINAE. Compilation fails with this error:

```
type_nonsense.cpp:20:5: error: no matching function for call to 'c'
    c(SOME::VALUE);
    ^
type_nonsense.cpp:13:6: note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer
      template argument 'T'
void c(typename std::enable_if<std::is_enum<T>::value, T>::type t) {}
     ^
1 error generated.
```

Moving the `std::enable_if` to either the return type or to a dummy template parameter works fine. Why?

---

```
#include <type_traits>

// Works
template <typename T, typename dummy = typename std::enable_if<std::is_enum<T>::value, T>::type>
void a(T t) {}

// Works
template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_enum<T>::value, void>::type b(T t) {}

// Fails to compile
template <typename T>
void c(typename std::enable_if<std::is_enum<T>::value, T>::type t) {}

enum class SOME { VALUE };

int main() {
    a(SOME::VALUE);
    b(SOME::VALUE);
    c(SOME::VALUE);
}
```

Comment: `template<class T> void func(std::vector<T>::iterator)` fails for exactly the same reason, nothing to do with SFINAE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A dependent type in a nested name specifier is a non-deduced context for template argument deduction, and as such cannot be used to determine the type of `T`. Placing the `std::enable_if` in either the return type or as a default template parameter works because the type of `T` isn't being deduced in those contexts.

If you need to place it as a parameter, you can do so like this:

```
template <typename T>
void c(T t, typename std::enable_if<std::is_enum<T>::value>::type* = nullptr) {}
```

This works because `T` is being deduced by the *first* argument, not the second.

Comment: Just curious, but would there ever be a case where you couldn't put it in the return?

Comment: @JamesKanze 14.8.2/7 ([temp.deduct]/p7) gives a good example where the placement of a dependent nested name specifier results in failure or success if used in the return type before the parameter list, in a trailing return-type, or in the parameter list.

Answer (score 1):

For the one which fails to compile, `T` is not deductible.